# Display this transparent image in axis (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, png, transparency, alpha

How do I display the image below on an axis in MATLAB with its transparency. The code below which worked with me for other transparent images does not seem to work with the image below.

```
A= imread('54fSK.png');
hhimage= imshow(A);
set(hhimage, 'AlphaData', A);
```

It gives me this error:

> Error using set
>
> Bad property value found.
>
> Object Name: image Property
>
> Name: 'AlphaData'.

This is the image I want to display with transparency:

[image: Image I want to display with transparency]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your A is of dimension 135x97x3, AlphaData should be of dimension 135x97x1.

try: `set(hhimage, 'AlphaData', A(:,:,1));`